# '4/20/22, 4:08 PM - ', how to format this date using python

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, data-science

I am not getting values its showing `NAT` at every date position

The code I used:

```
df['message_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['message_date'], format='%m/%d/%y, %I:%M %p -',errors="coerce")
```

Comment: What is the expected output  you want ? Can you modify and add that to your question! l

Answer (score -1):

Add space after `_`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"message_date": ["4/20/22, 4:08 PM - ", "4/20/22, 4:08 PM - "]})
print(df)
          message_date
0  4/20/22, 4:08 PM - 
1  4/20/22, 4:08 PM -

df['message_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['message_date'], format='%m/%d/%y, %I:%M %p - ',
                      errors="coerce")
print (df)
         message_date
0 2022-04-20 16:08:00
1 2022-04-20 16:08:00
```